# To print the first biggest and second biggest elements in a string

Tags: java

Below is the code I have implemented. My doubt here is: when I am trying to print the first biggest and second Biggest values in the string, the output I get is in the order of `[second biggest, first biggest]`.
Here is the output of what I got for the below code:

```
The output of the map is: real--6
The output of the map is: to--2
The output of the map is: world--1
The output of the map is: hello--0
The list after insertion is: [to, real]
The list inserted as [biggest,secondBiggest] after calling main is: [to, real]
......
```

but, I want `The list after insertion to be: [real, to]`.

```
public class ReadString {
    static String input = "This is a real project with real code to do real things to solve real problems in real world real";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> lst = ReadString.RepeatedString("This is a real project with real "
                + "code to do real things to solve real " + "problems in real world real");
        System.out.println("The list inserted as [biggest,secondBiggest] after calling main is: " + lst);
    }

    public static List<String> RepeatedString(String s) {

        String[] s2 = input.split(" ");
        String[] key = { "real", "to", "world", "hello" };
        int count = 0;
        Integer biggest = 0;
        Integer secondBiggest = 1;
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (int j = 0; j < key.length; j++) {
            count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < s2.length; i++) {
                if (s2[i].equals(key[j])) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            map.put(key[j], count);
            System.out.println("The output of the map is: " +key[j] + "--" + count);

        }

        /*
         * To find the top two most repeated values.
         */
        List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>(map.values());
        Collections.sort(values);
        for (int n : map.values()) {
            if (biggest < n) {
                secondBiggest = biggest;
                biggest = n;
            } else if (secondBiggest < n)
                secondBiggest = n;
        }
        /* To get the top most repeated strings. */

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String s1 : map.keySet()) {
            if (map.get(s1).equals(biggest))
                list.add(s1);
            else if (map.get(s1).equals(secondBiggest))
                list.add(s1);
        }
        System.out.println("The list after insertion is: " +list);
        return list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be when you are adding items to the list.  As you are iterating through the map.keySet(), there is no guarantee that you will get the biggest item first.  The smallest change I would make would be to add the biggest item first in the list.

```java
    for (String s1 : map.keySet()) {
        if (map.get(s1).equals(biggest))
            list.add(0, s1);
        else if (map.get(s1).equals(secondBiggest))
            list.add(s1);
    }
```

This way, if secondBiggest is added first, biggest will be at the top of the list.

Comment: I was just about to post this solution as well. However, shouldn't it be 'list.add(0, s1);' instead? Inserting it at index 1 will still insert it after the secondBiggest string, if it was encountered first.

Answer (score 0):

We can simplify your approach quite a bit if we extract the `word` and `count` into a simple POJO. Something like,

```
static class WordCount implements Comparable<WordCount> {
    String word;
    int count;
    WordCount(String word, int count) {
        this.word = word;
        this.count = count;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(WordCount o) {
        return Integer.compare(count, o.count);
    }
}
```

Then we can use that in `repeatedString`. First, count the words in the `String`; then build a `List` of `WordCount`(s). Sort it (since it's `Comparable` it has natural ordering). Then build the `List` to return by iterating the sorted `List` of `WordCount`(s) in reverse (for two items). Like,

```
static List<String> repeatedString(String s) {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (String word : s.split("\\s+")) {
        map.put(word, !map.containsKey(word) ? 1 : 1 + map.get(word));
    }
    List<WordCount> al = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        al.add(new WordCount(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
    }
    Collections.sort(al);
    List<String> ret = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = al.size() - 1; i >= al.size() - 2; i--) {
        ret.add(al.get(i).word);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Finally, your `main` method should use your `static input` (or `static input` should be removed)

```
static String input = "This is a real project with real code to do "
        + "real things to solve real problems in real world real";
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> lst = repeatedString(input);
    System.out.println("The list inserted as [biggest,"
            + "secondBiggest] after calling main is: " + lst);
}
```

And I get (as requested)

```
The list inserted as [biggest,secondBiggest] after calling main is: [real, to]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only concerned about biggest and secondbiggest,
you can refer to the code below.
Instead of creating the list directly, I created an array, added required elements on specified positions. (This way it becomes more readable)
and finally convert the array to a list.

```
        /* To get the top most repeated strings. */
        String[] resultArray = new String[2];
        for (String s1 : map.keySet()) {
            if (map.get(s1).equals(biggest))
            resultArray[0]=s1;
            else if (map.get(s1).equals(secondBiggest))
            resultArray[1]=s1;
        }
        List<String> list =  Arrays.asList(resultArray);
```